# What am I wrong in solving $\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos \frac{n^2+1}{3}2\pi$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have calculated

Case 1: $n=3k$
Case 2: $n=3k+1$
Case 3: $n=3k+2$

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos \frac{n^2+1}{3}2\pi=-\frac12$

So the limit should exist,

However,

[image]

Am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, but neither is WA. As WA says, it is assuming the limit is continuous, i.e. $n$ is a real number, not just an integer, which would make the limit not exist. If you click "discrete", you might get a better result.

Comment: This is true only when $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Click on the **Assuming limit refers to a continuous limit | Use the discrete instead** option

Comment: I see!!! thanks @TheoBendit

Comment: Thanks !!!!! @19aksh